# failed lookup view with express server and gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm having a problem connecting an express server with a gulp serve/r task. In order to send my views to the DOM, I need express to do that. I'd like my server to run as a gulp task. The server runs, however when I try to access my local url it runs an error in browser:

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "C:\Users\User Name\Documents\project\src\scripts"
```

My app.js

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');
var path = require('path');

var hbs = exphbs.create({ /* config */ });
var app = express();

//environment variable
var port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

// static files + template engine
app.engine('handlebars', hbs.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '../scripts'));

app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

//http request method get json list
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index');
});

app.listen(port);
```

My file structure looks like this:

```
project
|-- src
|     |-- css
|     |-- scripts
|          |-- app.js
|     |-- index.html
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you add the `views` directory to the file structure you displayed?

Comment: @gnerkus i don't have a views file. Does express absolutely need it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change this:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '../scripts'));
```

to this:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '..'));
```

This is because the `index.html` file resides in the `src` directory which is a parent of the `scripts` directory from which the script is executed.

Comment: runs the same error: Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "C:\Users\User Name\Documents\project\src"